# Execution of threads in a queue in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, reentrantlock

I have this exercise:

> Develop a multi-threaded application.
>   Use java.util.concurrent opportunities.
>
> **DONT USE: synchronized, BlockingQueue, BlockingDeque**
>
> All entities wishing to access a resource must be threads. Use the
>   opportunities of OOP.

And my task is:

> Free cashDesk. Fast food restaurant has a few cash Desks. Client stand in queue at a particular cash Desk, but may go
>   to another cash Desk if reduction or disappearance of the queue there.

**Here is my solution https://github.com/NikitaMitroshin/FreeCash**

```
public class Restaurant {
    private static Restaurant instance = null;
    private static ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<CashDesk> cashDesks;

    private Restaurant(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        cashDesks = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public static Restaurant getInstance(String name) {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new Restaurant(name);
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void addCashDesk(CashDesk cashDesk) {
        cashDesks.add(cashDesk);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public List<CashDesk> getCashDesks() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(cashDesks);
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
public class Client extends Thread {
    private final static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Client.class);
    private Restaurant restaurant;
    private CashDesk cashDesk;
    private String name;
    private int itemsInOrder;

    public Client(Restaurant restaurant, int itemsInOrder, String name) {
        this.restaurant = restaurant;
        this.itemsInOrder = itemsInOrder;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getClientName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getItemsInOrder() {
        return itemsInOrder;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Client " + name + " comes to restaurant " + restaurant.getName());
        this.cashDesk = chooseCashDesk();
        System.out.println("Client " + getClientName() + " choosed the cashDesk#"+ cashDesk.getNumber());
        cashDesk.addClient(this);
        while (true) {
            if (cashDesk.getLock().tryLock()) {
                try {
                    cashDesk.serveClient(this);
                } catch (ResourceException e) {
                    LOG.error("ResourceException!!! ", e);
                } finally {
                    cashDesk.getLock().unlock();
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                if (canChooseAnotherCashDesk()) {
                    cashDesk.removeClient(this);
                }
            }
        }
        cashDesk.removeClient(this);
        System.out.println("Client " + getClientName() + " leaves restaurant");
    }

    private CashDesk chooseCashDesk(){
        CashDesk result = restaurant.getCashDesks().get(0);
        for (CashDesk cashDesk : restaurant.getCashDesks()) {
            if(cashDesk.getClients().size() < result.getClients().size()) {
                result = cashDesk;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private boolean canChooseAnotherCashDesk() {
        CashDesk result = chooseCashDesk();
        if(result.getClients().size() + 1 < cashDesk.getClients().size()) {
            cashDesk = result;
            cashDesk.addClient(this);
            System.out.println("Client " + getClientName() + " moved to cashDesk#" + cashDesk.getNumber());
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

CashDesk code:

```
public class CashDesk {

    private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private LinkedList<Client> clients;
    private int number;
    private int timeOfService;

    public CashDesk(int number, int timeOfService) {
        clients = new LinkedList<>();
        this.number = number;
        this.timeOfService = timeOfService;

    }

    public void serveClient(Client client) throws ResourceException {
        System.out.println("Client "+client.getClientName() + " is serving on cashDesk#"+getNumber());
        try {
            client.sleep(timeOfService * client.getItemsInOrder());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new ResourceException("InterruptedException!!!", e);
        }
        System.out.println("Client "+client.getClientName() + " is served");
    }

    public List<Client> getClients() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(clients);
    }

    public void addClient(Client client) {
        clients.add(client);
    }

    public void removeClient(Client client) {
        clients.remove(client);
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public ReentrantLock getLock() {
        return lock;
    }
}
```

Runner code:

```
public class RestaurantRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Restaurant restaurant = Restaurant.getInstance("Mcdonalds");
        CashDesk cashDesk1 = new CashDesk(1, 140);
        CashDesk cashDesk2 = new CashDesk(2, 250);

        restaurant.addCashDesk(cashDesk1);
        restaurant.addCashDesk(cashDesk2);


        new Client(restaurant, 100, "client50").start();
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {

            int randNumbOfItems = random.nextInt(10) + 1;
            Client client =  new Client(restaurant, randNumbOfItems, "client"+i);
            client.start();
        }
    }
}
```

And I have problem with it. That's what I get after running my application

```
Client client1 comes to restaurant Mcdonalds
Client client1 choosed the cashDesk#1
Client client1 is serving on cashDesk#1
Client client3 comes to restaurant Mcdonalds
Client client3 choosed the cashDesk#2
Client client3 is serving on cashDesk#2
Client client5 comes to restaurant Mcdonalds
Client client5 choosed the cashDesk#1
Client client6 comes to restaurant Mcdonalds
Client client6 choosed the cashDesk#2
Client client4 comes to restaurant Mcdonalds
Client client4 choosed the cashDesk#1
Client client50 comes to restaurant Mcdonalds
Client client50 choosed the cashDesk#2
Client client7 comes to restaurant Mcdonalds
Client client7 choosed the cashDesk#1
Client client2 comes to restaurant Mcdonalds
Client client2 choosed the cashDesk#2
Client client1 is served
Client client5 is serving on cashDesk#1
Client client1 leaves restaurant
Client client3 is served
Client client3 leaves restaurant
Client client50 is serving on cashDesk#2
Client client5 is served
Client client5 leaves restaurant
Client client7 is serving on cashDesk#1
Client client7 is served
Client client7 leaves restaurant
Client client6 moved to cashDesk#1
Client client6 is serving on cashDesk#1
Client client2 moved to cashDesk#1
Client client6 is served
Client client6 leaves restaurant
Client client2 is serving on cashDesk#1
Client client2 is served
Client client2 leaves restaurant
Client client4 is serving on cashDesk#1
Client client4 is served
Client client4 leaves restaurant
Client client50 is served
Client client50 leaves restaurant
```

So, as you can see queue of service is disturbed.

When client3 is served client6 must start serving, but client50 doing this. And when client5 is served client4 must start serving, but client7 doing this. And when client7 is served I dont know why but client6 moving to cashDesk#1 and starts serving, despite the fact that client4 must start serving.

I'm novice at multithreading so I need an advice, how to get my application work correctly

Comment: You are supposed to include your code in the question - the relevant parts at least. A link to GIThub is not a good idea as few people will bother to browse there. Also, your question seems to be machine-translated at least in part, and that makes it hard to understand. I see you are also active on the Russian SO. Wouldn't it be better to post there?

Comment: @RealSkeptic what is hard to understand? I can try to explain this

Comment: I think you can get a `ConcurrentModificationException` on the `CashDesk.clients` list: multiple threads (`Client`s) can change this list at the same time. Synchronizing the list using `Collections.synchronizedList` would probably be a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You talked about queues in the title but you didn't use them in your code. In fact when the first client (client5) comes at the cashdesk1, the cashdesk is locked to serve this client.

```
  //client code
          while (true) {
        if (cashDesk.getLock().tryLock()) {  //the cashdesk is locked
            try {
                cashDesk.serveClient(this);
```

Meanwhile other clients come since there is a service time. So client4 and client7 are waiting at the cashdesk1
When client5 is served, client5 releases the lock

```
  //client code
   cashDesk.getLock().unlock();
```

So the next one to be served is the first to grab the lock and since it is an infinite loop you cannot know at which position in your code each client is. So client7 grabs it first before client4. Moreover reading your output, client2 grabs it before too.
I suggest you remove the lock and use a variable to specify the order

```
 //CashDesk
  Client current=null;
  public void nextClient() 
  {
    if(clients.size()==0)
        current=null;
    else
        current = clients.get(0);
 }
```

Replace the portion following code

```
 while (true) {
        if (cashDesk.getLock().tryLock()) {
            try {
                cashDesk.serveClient(this);
            } catch (ResourceException e) {
                LOG.error("ResourceException!!! ", e);
            } finally {
                cashDesk.getLock().unlock();
                break;
            }
        } else {
            if (canChooseAnotherCashDesk()) {
                cashDesk.removeClient(this);
            }
        }
    }
```

by

```
  while (true) {
        if(cashDesk.current==null)
             cashDesk.nextClient();
        if (current==this) {
            try {
                cashDesk.serveClient(this);
            } catch (ResourceException e) {
                LOG.error("ResourceException!!! ", e);
            } finally {
                cashDesk.nextClient();
                break;
            }
        } else {
            if (canChooseAnotherCashDesk()) {
                cashDesk.removeClient(this);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> So, as you can see queue of service is disturbed.

It is not disturbed. It works as designed by you actually.

> *ReentrantLock documentation:*
>
> The constructor for this class accepts an optional fairness parameter.
>   When set true, under contention, locks favor granting access to the
>   longest-waiting thread. **Otherwise this lock does not guarantee any
>   particular access order.** Programs using fair locks accessed by many
>   threads may display lower overall throughput (i.e., are slower; often
>   much slower) than those using the default setting, but have smaller
>   variances in times to obtain locks and guarantee lack of starvation.
>
> **Note however, that fairness of locks does not guarantee fairness of
>   thread scheduling. Thus, one of many threads using a fair lock may
>   obtain it multiple times in succession while other active threads are
>   not progressing and not currently holding the lock.**
>
> **Also note that the
>   untimed tryLock method does not honor the fairness setting. It will
>   succeed if the lock is available even if other threads are waiting.**

Try to get acquainted with the use of `ReentrantLock`. The fairness parameter (you can pass it as a value to the [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#ReentrantLock(boolean))) is a first step to see if your clients get served in the order you'd like them to.
The both solutions (the other answer suggests to use a variable to control order, though I'm not a big fan of that - or my suggestion with a fairness parameter set) and get back to us with more feedback.